# Min weighted path in a graph, but you could die

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal

The min-path problem is mostly motivated by a graph with cities as vertices and roads between them as edges. Each edge has a weight which could be the length of the road or the time it takes to cross it in your car ($t_e$ for edge $e$). This problem has an optimal substructure (sub-paths within an optimal path are also optimal) and is thus conducive to greedy strategies and dynamic programming.

Let's add a dark twist now. As you traverse each edge, there is a probability, $p_e$ that you will survive. Maybe because the roads have dangerous drivers or there could be someone waiting to ambush you.

You start off at a source vertex and aim to get to a destination vertex. Also, you're part of a large column of tanks and you want to get a lot of them at the destination fast, so all you care about is the rate of arrival at the destination. It can be shown that this rate along any path with edges indexed by $i$ is:

$$\lambda_p = \frac{\prod p_i}{\sum t_i}$$

You want the path that has the highest rate of arrival between the source and destination.

The optimal substructure property now applies to both the numerator and the denominator, but not to $\lambda_p$. How then do we go about solving this? Is it NP-hard? Any clever heuristic if so?

Note: some people will recognize this is motivated by the Ukraine war and just in case you're curious, my position on it is that it should stop immediately to prevent further loss of life.

Comment: What is "rate of arrival"? It's clearly not the expected time to reach the destination (which is what I'd think you'd want to optimize for), since that depends on which edges on the path have which $p$-values, while $\lambda_p$ does not. For example, if every edge has $p=1$ except the last one which has $p=0.01$, the expected time is going to be much higher than if the singular $p=0.01$ is the first edge; but $\lambda_p$ is the same in both cases.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sum t_i}$ is the rate at which you arrive (average arrivals per unit time) if you never die. But then there is a probability $\prod p_i$ (not $1$) that you will arrive. So, the net rate is $\lambda_p$. But regardless, this interpretation doesn't necessarily have to have a justification as far as the graph theory problem goes.

Comment: Also, the expected time to reach the destination is infinity since there is a finite probability that you'll never arrive.

Comment: How is there a finite probability you will jever arrive? This is approximately a geometrical distribution over the number of steps done until arrival...

Comment: I mean you'll never arrive in one life. And you always respawn at the source. Let's say you have a finite number of respawns.. then it is finite, right?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I think I see the problem now. I was thinking in terms of columns of tanks originally. Shouldn't have added the "respawn" angle. If its just a large number of tanks and some percentage of them is going to make it through the path in the graph, the $\lambda_p$ formulation works for your example too. Let me know if I'm mistaken.